# Count text using Query with ImportRange

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a table using Query with Importrange to count how many times a particular event has occurred for a particular employer. The data sheet has over 500 rows but this is a sample of the data:

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16mdnqgOF4Q6uIxLFzIy-Q0-jpBqzT1z9aAImwkqNl0Y/edit?usp=sharing)

I want the Query to result in the following data in another Sheet but in the same Spreadsheet:

[image: Query]

This is my formula

```js
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-f6OU8ylDSlpqdpt4P5B7GDcIel3IboVkUbY2huMA6U", "Events/Incidents!A2:Y"),"select Col3, Col5 where Col9='Accident' Count(Col9) Group by Count(Col9) Order by Count(Col9) desc limit 20", 1)
```

I can't get the Query to count text in column I = Accident. Would really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close with your query.  Try this:

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-f6OU8ylDSlpqdpt4P5B7GDcIel3IboVkUbY2huMA6U", "Events/Incidents!A2:Y"),"select Col3, Col5, Count(Col9) where Col9='Accident' Group by Col3,Col5 order by Count(Col9) desc limit 20", 1)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your query needs to be altered.

Please try the following:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-f6OU8ylDSlpqdpt4P5B7GDcIel3IboVkUbY2huMA6U", "Events/Incidents!A2:Y"),"select Col3, Col5, count(Col9) where Col9='Accident' group by Col3, Col5 Order by Count(Col9) desc limit 20", 1)
```